# Change in momentum zero but force applied is positive!

Tags: classical-mechanics

A mass of $6\text{ kg}$ is suspended by a rope of length $2 \text{ m}$ from the ceiling. Assuming $g=10 \text{ m s}^{-1}$, force of $60 \text{ N}$ is applied on the object in the direction of floor from ceiling.

Now, I am taught that $F=\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t}$, where $P$ is momentum, $t$ is time and $F$ is force. But,  $F{\Delta t}=\Delta P$ says that with passage of time, change in momentum should increase!! This is contrary to the assumption that mass is tied and stationary (as well as contrary to observations like ceiling fan over my head has zero momentum unless I switch it on.)

Please help me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a free body diagram for this situation?

Comment: Note that the $F$ in Newton's Second Law refers to the *net* force. Think about what other forces might be relevant in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the equation representing Newton's second law $$ \vec F = m \frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$

$\vec F$ is the **net force** (which is the sum of all forces) and if there is no acceleration, $\large \frac{d\vec v}{dt}=0$ and the net force $\vec F=0$. And if we apply the same reasoning to this case,
initially have an object hanging from a ceiling. This means that $$\vec F=\vec T-m\vec g=0 $$ The zero on the right hand side means the system is in *equilibrium*.

In situations where the net force is not zero, then $$ \vec F = m \frac{d\vec v}{dt} = m\vec a$$ and $\vec a$ is the acceleration resulting from the net force. In other words, $$ \vec F d t = m d \vec v = \Delta \vec P$$ or $$\text{Impulse}=\text{Change in momentum}$$ which is consistent with your original assumption.

> as well as contrary to observations like ceiling fan over my head has zero momentum unless I switch it on

Yes, the ceiling fan is in equilibrium. And when you switch it on, it is still in *vertical equilibrium*. What has happened when you turn it on, is that electrical energy causes a torque on the fan blades leading to the fan acquiring *angular momentum* which will be uniform (net torque $\tau$ is zero, so the *change in angular momentum* $\vec L = 0$). Also, as an interesting side note, if say one of the blades has a mass/shape slightly (or not slightly) differing to the others, you will note that the fan [precesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) since there now is a net torque and the angular momentum changes once again according to Newton's second law for rotating objects, $$\vec \tau=\frac {d\vec L}{dt}=I\vec \alpha$$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\alpha$ is *angular acceleration*.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law states that in order for something to change its momentum, we have to apply a force.

Since the object is suspended by a rope, its momentum does not change, therefore it looks like no new force was added. However, if we pull the object down without changing its position, then the new force from pulling is exactly compensated by the upwards force inside the rope.

The same force has been holding the object up against the force of gravity, and now the rope has to balance both gravity and you pulling down.